# Error while generating report in Jmeter 5.2.1

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

**Command Used** : ./jmeter -n -t TESTSIT.jmx -JTestEnv=sit2 -l ResultLog.log -e -o ResultLog

the same command generates result from local cmd and gives following exception from ec2 instance

**Error message**
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Cannot create temporary file for channel #0

Comment: Check the `saveservice` settings in the properties file are the same both on your local machine and ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure your EC2 instance has enough free disk space? You can check it using i.e. [`df` command](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1p-df/)

Second, it is not very possible to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing the full [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), however my another assumption is that your EC2 user doesn't have write access to the OS temporary folder. You can amend `jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir` property and point it to the folder where you have write access for sure, i.e.

```
./jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir=/tmp -g ResultLog.log -o ResultLog
```

If it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the above line to *user.properties* or *reportgenerator.properties* file.

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)